# React-Native: Android Webview very slow with AngularJS-Website

Tags: android, webview, react-native

I threw together an example project with the webview in it. What perplexes me is that loading the Angular-page with Android is ca. 3x slower than loading it with iOS. Am I missing something?

I tried turning on hardware acceleration bc I read it somewhere but hardly does anything. I'm aware this is a vague question, still hope I could get some hints.

The code is just the sample:

```
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <WebView
        source={{uri: 'https://AngularSite'}} />
   </View>
```